# stopping values overlapping each other in a bar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i avoid values overlapping into each other and the bars infront?

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=300,%<- added ymax
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box, Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,54) (Gaussian,86)  (Box,154) (Sobel,268)  };%CPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,170.71) (Gaussian, 172.065)  (Box,193.72) (Sobel,215.38)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  (Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) };%FPGA
\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA}
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=300,%<- added ymax
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box, Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,21) (Gaussian,32)  (Box,27) (Sobel,40)  };%CPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,162.49) (Gaussian, 158.74)  (Box,178.76) (Sobel,169.79)  };%GPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,) (Gaussian,)  (Box,) (Sobel,) };%FPGA
\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Algorithms Including Image Read/Write }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Apparently, the account i created with the same email didnt work. but that accounts mine also?

Comment: EDIT* I managed to sync both accounts @Schrödinger'scat Im trying out tikz as my graphs for a paper so its the first time using this type of package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another blunt way: rotate the nodes and vary the anchors between the two `axis` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=300,%<- added ymax
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box, Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=-90,inner xsep=1pt}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,54) (Gaussian,86)  (Box,154) (Sobel,268)  };%CPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,170.71) (Gaussian, 172.065)  (Box,193.72) (Sobel,215.38)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  (Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) };%FPGA
\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA}
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=300,%<- added ymax
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box, Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=west,rotate=-90,inner xsep=1pt}
    ]
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,21) (Gaussian,32)  (Box,27) (Sobel,40)  };%CPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,162.49) (Gaussian, 158.74)  (Box,178.76) (Sobel,169.79)  };%GPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,) (Gaussian,)  (Box,) (Sobel,) };%FPGA
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Algorithms Including Image Read/Write.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I'd like to ask you to post minimal but complete codes that start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. As in this answer, many things depend on the settings of the document.